# How do I only keep the most recent n entries in a log4net sql table?

Tags: log4net

I am using log4net to log to a sql table. I'd like to be able to either only keep the most recent n days, or the most recent n entries in the table. Is this possible with log4net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, for the `commandText` for the AdoNetAppender I set the command text to:

```
<commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception); DELETE FROM [Log] WHERE [Date] &lt; DATEADD(dd, -28, GETDATE())" />
```

It feels hacky, but it works. I'll post here if I find a neater solution.

Comment: lol, thought about that but figured I wouldn't advise it. Since it will put more load into the logging process, I would do the deletion out-of-band in a separate process.

Comment: As a general principle I think you're right, but since our logging is mostly going to be fairly low levels I think it's an acceptable overhead. If I'm wrong we can pull it out and use your suggestion.

Comment: it feels so wrong to do something like this. Especially considering how easy it would be to write a sql job to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Log4net do not have this capability built-in. But such a task is probably best placed as a job ,e.g. in SSIS (if you're running MS SQL Server) or similar tools.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party... but looking at [ilivewithian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48886/ilivewithian)'s solution I would agree with [Peter Lillevold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35245/peter-lillevold)'s observation that having it cause additional load in the logging process is undesirable.

Wouldn't it also be possible to use a trigger in the database to auto-delete the older items? Sure, you would need a DB that supports triggers, but it seems like most modern ones (including open source ones like SQLite and PostgreSQL) do.